# Get/Pass Order Collection From Block/phtml to controller

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, sales-order

I am using magento 1.9 version.
I am having custom order collection in Block and also i can get it in related phtml file too.

But i need the collection data in controller to export CSV.

I tried by setting collection in `session` and `registry`. No luck.

How to get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Got it using this code

`$this->getLayout()->getBlockSingleton('mymodule/block_name')->getCollection()->getData()`